# Ensure variable is passed as an integer

Tags: json, perl

How do I ensure that a variable value is passed as an integer?  I have a variable that is being passed to a JSON call,  if I set the value via getopts and then pass the value to JSON in an event, it fails.  This fails regardless of whether the value is entered on the command line or via the set default.

For example:

```
my $code = $opt_s||'4';
```

However, if I set hardcode the value like so:

```
$code = '4';
```

This works.

The API is expecting that an int be provided.  I am assuming that my variable is being converted into a string in the first case but, i cannot figure out how to stop this behavior.

Thanks
Bee

Comment: `$code = '4'` is not setting a string not an integer. The reason `||` isn't working is because `$opt_s` must have some kind of value.

Comment: Are you really using `getopts.pl`? Consider to switch to `Getopt::Long`.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider that a buggy API, since Perl considers signed integer (IV) four, unsigned integer (UV) four, floating point number (NV) four, 8-bit string (PV,UTF8=0) four and 72-bit string (PV,UTF8=1) four as the same value. (And that's not even counting overloaded objects and magical variables!)

You can convert the representation of the value to one of the numerical formats (IV, UV or NV) using an operation that takes a number and returns a number:

```
0+$code
```

If you want an IV specifically, you might have to access the perlapi.

Comment: `int(0+$code)` always seems to produce an IV for me (unless `$code` gets larger than ~1E18).

Comment: @mob, are you saying `0+$code` doesn't (for integer numbers), or are merely pointing out that `0+$code` could return a `0.5` for `'0.5'`

Comment: @ikegami I would not say that the other API is buggy. It's probably written in another language, which may take the difference between integer and string more seriously.

Answer (score 0):

To get the integer part of a number use `int()` http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html

Also see:

Does Perl have a round() function? What about ceil() and floor()?
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Does-Perl-have-a-round%28%29-function%3F-What-about-ceil%28%29-and-floor%28%29%3F-Trig-functions%3F

Comment: This is not the question here. Problem is that depending on internal state of a Perl SV a JSON serializer may create `{"something":4}` or `{"something":"4"}`, and the difference may matter for other deserializers.